# Error using fortify() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile

I am creating a map using the zip code information from the census data together with data that I have for each zip code.

I obtained the shapefiles for the zip codes from https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-cart-boundary.html.

I successfully read in the shapefiles using readOGR with the following code:

```
Zip = readOGR("C:\\...pathname....\\cb_2013_us_zcta510_500k.shp")
```

I am running into a problem when I try to use fortify so that I can combine the information from the shapefile with my data.

```
names(Zip)
[1] "ZCTA5CE10"  "AFFGEOID10" "GEOID10"    "ALAND10"    "AWATER10"  
test = ggplot2::fortify(Zip, region="AWATER10")
Error in fortify.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Zip, region = "AWATER10") : 
`region' not supported
```

The error is replicated when I try all of the results from names(Zip). I am not sure which column contains the zip code information that I am interested in, so I just tried all of them.

My ultimate goal is to use the zip code information with ggmap to fill in the zip codes with different colors based on information in my data.

Comment: `readShapeSpatial` =/= `readOGR`. The former is from `maptools` and the latter from `rgdal` package. So you don't use `readOGR`.

Comment: Do you have `gpclib` installed and have run `gpclibPermit()`? In that case, I can't reproduce the error. Could you post the result of running the traceback? Also, re: this- do you have the mosaic package loaded?

Comment: @Pascal I got the same error even when I read in the shape file using readOGR (Zip2 = readOGR(dsn="...pathname...", layer="cb_2013_us_zcta510_500k")

Comment: @DavidRobinson When I try to install gpclib, I get the following:

"Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
  ‘gpclib’
  These will not be installed"

Comment: It is to point out that you say you are using `readOGR`, but in your example you use `readShapeSpatial`.

Comment: `readOGR` works for you without specified layer?

Comment: Do you have `rgeos` installed and loaded? `install.packages("rgeos"); require("rgeos")`?

Comment: BTW: that's a whopper of a shapefile! Can you reproduce the error with a smaller file?

Comment: Reloading all of the packages solved the problem, I am not sure why, but it worked!